# Problems in the configuration proxy on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, proxy, pip

I work behind a proxy and I have tried to install a python package with pip from the terminal but it shows the following error (I have tried to install electronjs with `npm` and it also gives me errors with the network):

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fed4cdc32e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/virtualenv/
```

I work with `cntlm` and in the network options I did the following configuration:

[image: network configuration]

I edited the `/etc/environment` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` files as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/environment
http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
ftp_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"
```

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3128";
```

Comment: When you open the terminal, does the `env` command output contain proxy settings shown above?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be with the proxy settings, I have checked the settings with other Ubuntu users at my university. We think there is something wrong with the proxy or the network.

Comment: The proxy is set to your own machine. Have you checked that the proxy software is working? Are you able to reach the Internet via browser with these proxy settings?

Comment: Yes, I haven't problems with the browser, nor with other programs connected to internet such as vscode but I can't install from the snapstore or install packages using npm. pip3.....

Comment: I would ask again, is the proxy setting visible in output of the `env` command, in the very same terminal where you try to run `pip`?

Comment: Yes,no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.0.0.0/8,*.uci.cu
ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.0.0.0/8,*.uci.cu
FTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128/
ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:3128/
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:3128/

Comment: AFAIK it's wrong syntax. The variables should be: `http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128 https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128` and so on. But these two variables should be sufficient for `pip`, I think. Change them to include `http:` prefix and check if it helps.

Comment: I have tried the configuration you suggest and it still does not work, however, other programs like vscode communicate with the internet without problems.

Comment: Did you try to run `pip` with the `--proxy 127.0.0.1:3128` parameter ?

Comment: Yes, I did and nothing

Comment: And do the logs of your `cntlm` show anything interesting?